# What is the best way to check my RAID HDDs from windows?

Tags: windows-server-2003, raid, hard-drive

I have a file server (2003) and I want to be able to check if the HDDs are good or not. They've been running for over 3 years.

Answer (score 1):

Try [THIS](http://www.passmark.com/products/diskcheckup.htm) or [THIS](http://www.ariolic.com/activesmart/index.html), basically something that looks at your server's SMART counters - if you'd let us know what your server and/or disk-controller is we might be able to help more.

Answer (score 0):

If your server has SMB software you have to use that to monitor the predicted failure status. Dell, HP, etcetera should have a download on the support site where you can download the management software.

If no SMB but you are using hardware raid you'll have to reboot during a maintenance period to check the array status in the raid controller.

If no hardware raid or SMB then you can use HDTune, Speedfan, CrystalDiskInfo, or any of dozens of other programs to monitor the smart data.